# Composable not recomposing when first param did not change

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

```
@Composable
fun DeviceDetailScreen(
    viewModel: DeviceDetailViewModel = viewModel(),
) {
    val deviceDetails by viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    val deviceLocation by viewModel.uiLocationState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    ...
    DeviceDetailHeaderDataRow(deviceDetails, deviceLocation)
}

@Composable
private fun DeviceDetailHeaderDataRow(
    deviceDetails: DeviceDetailUiState,
    deviceLocation: DeviceDetailLocationUiState,
) {
}
```

I debugged and added some logs to be sure, when deciveDetails gets emitted in the View Model, DeviceDetailHeaderDataRow gets recomposed, but then deviceLocation gets emitted and I see the line calling DeviceDetailHeaderDataRow running but the function itself gets never recomponsed, deviceDetails stays the same, but deviceLocation has 100% changed, it seems as it is ignoring deviceLocation and just checking if deviceDetails changed or not.

ViewModel:

```
private val _uiState: MutableStateFlow<DeviceDetailUiState> = MutableStateFlow(DeviceDetailUiState.Loading)
    val uiState: StateFlow<DeviceDetailUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    private val _uiLocationState: MutableStateFlow<DeviceDetailLocationUiState> = MutableStateFlow(DeviceDetailLocationUiState.Loading)
    val uiLocationState: StateFlow<DeviceDetailLocationUiState> = _uiLocationState.asStateFlow()

sealed class DeviceDetailUiState {
    data class Success(val data: DeviceDetailHeaderState) : DeviceDetailUiState()
    object Loading : DeviceDetailUiState()
}

sealed class DeviceDetailLocationUiState {
    data class Success(val data: LocationPathState) : DeviceDetailLocationUiState()
    object Loading : DeviceDetailLocationUiState()
    object Error : DeviceDetailLocationUiState()
}

data class LocationPathState(
    val location: List<LocationPath> = emptyList(),
)

data class DeviceDetailHeaderState(
    val imageUrl: String? = "",
    val deviceId: String = "",
)

private suspend fun collectDeviceLocationDetails() {
    customerLocationRepo.resource()
        .asFlow()
        .map {
            evaluateLocationResource(it, locationId.value)
        }
        .collect { newUiState ->
            Timber.tag("++").d("collectDeviceLocationDetails newUiState collect $newUiState")
            _uiLocationState.emit(newUiState)
        }
}

private fun evaluateLocationResource(
    location: Resource<List<Location>>,
    locationId: String,
): DeviceDetailLocationUiState {
    when (location) {
        ...
        is Resource.Success -> {
            Timber.tag("+++").d("evaluateLocationResource return ${location.data.size}")
            val locationData = location.data
            return DeviceDetailLocationUiState.Success(
                LocationPathState(
                    location = locationData.generateLocationList(locationId = locationId),
                ),
            )
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please include your `DeviceDetailLocationUiState` class and how you populate your `uiLocationState` flow.

Comment: @ianhanniballake added them

Comment: The problem is in your composable, not in viewModel, Recomposition just happens when you read the values, not write

Answer (score 0):

Updating from compose 1.5.0-beta03 to 1.5.4 which required me to also update kotlin from 1.8.22 to 1.9.20 and gradle from 8.0.2 to 8.2.0-rc03 and kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion from 1.4.8 to 1.5.4 solved the issue.